# How to select row pairs that match certain criteria in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of things. Here is a simplified structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `things` (
  `thing_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `thing_group` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `thing_status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);
```

There are 2 types of things. Primary, which would have `thing_id = thing_group` and secondary, which would having a unqiue thing_id but the same thing_group as the primary item.

```
INSERT INTO `things` (`thing_id`, `thing_group`, `thing_status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 3, 1),
(4, 3, 0),
(5, 5, 1),
(6, 5, 1),
(7, 7, 0),
(8, 7, 0),
(9, 9, 1),
(10, 9, 1),
```

I have thousands of these pairs.

`thing_status` can be 0 for either the primary or the secondary (or both), but I want to select ONLY a pair (at random) that has `thing_status` = 1 both for primary and secondary thing.

So from the sample data I provided, it should only return pairs which are either `thing_id` 5 and 6, or 9 and 10 (at random)

Hard part:
Some things can just have the primary thing only, and no secondary.  The query should still return those and treat them equally to things that come in pairs.

Am i better off doing 2 queries or a convoluted single query?

Comment: can you clearify your problem

Answer (score 0):

My intuition says that you should use 2 queries with a `UNION ALL`. But... with MySQL it's not always clear what works and what doesn't.

I believe that this query does what you want though:

```
SELECT t1.thing_id, t1.group_id
FROM things t1
LEFT JOIN things t2
    ON t2.thing_id = t2.thing_group
    AND t1.thing_id != t2.thing_id
WHERE (
    t1.thing_id = t1.thing_group
    AND t2.thing_id IS NULL
) OR (
    t1.thing_group = t2.thing_id
    AND t1.thing_id != t1.thing_group
)
GROUP BY t1.thing_id, t1.group_id
```

Comment: Thats pretty much the as WHERE thing_id = 1 AND thing_group = 1 ? which doesn't help much in my situation.

Comment: @k1lljoy: I suppose it does not, I'll re-read your question and respond in the morning. I am too tired right now :) I don't think I'm getting the problem fully...

Answer (score 0):

Group your rows by `thing_group` and select those where the number of rows is the same as the sum of `thing_status`. Join the resulting set back to the original table on `thing_group` to obtain the actual rows corresponding to the groups. So:

```
SELECT
  t.thing_id,
  t.thing_group
FROM things t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT thing_group
  FROM things
  GROUP BY thing_group
  HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(thing_status)
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 1
) g ON t.thing_group = g.thing_group
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so hard, maybe the random part is a bit more tricky:

```
select * 
from things 
where 
  thing_group = (select thing_group
                 from things 
                 where thing_status = 1 
                 group by thing_group
                 having count(thing_id) = 2
                 limit 1)
limit 1
```